# ROS2 - modify py launchfile without rebuilding package

Tags: ros2, build, colcon, launch-file

In ROS1 we could modify XML launchfile and roslaunch them directly without catkin_make rebuilding, in ROS2 it seems if I modify python launchfile, I need to rebuild the package otherwise

```
ros2 launch <package_name> <launchfile_name>
```

runs the old launchfile. Do I need to rebuild the package after each modification or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--symlink-install` flag while building your code. This will create symlinks in the install directory which points to actual source files rather then creating copies. So whenever you make change in your source files it will automatically be reflected in install and you won't be required to build again. You can also check this link, [what is the use of --symlink-install in ROS2 colcon build?](https://answers.ros.org/question/371822/what-is-the-use-of-symlink-install-in-ros2-colcon-build/), for further help.

Comment: Thanks, I mindlessly removed that option without reading what it does 